# Custom view pager indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

First, English is not my mother language and (i think) this question is quite complicated, so feel free to edit my question and please bear with me.

I want to create this UI :

[image]

My problem is the view pager is not a normal view pager. This is the scenario :

1. I have 5 menu, with the 3rd menu currently active
2. The 2nd menu indicator is on the left, and the 4th menu indicator is on the right
3. User swipe to LEFT
4. The 4th menu will be activated
5. The 2nd menu disappeared to the left, the 5th menu appeared on the right.
6. The 3rd menu indicator is on the left, and the 5th menu indicator is on the right.

That is what i tried to achieved. Is it possible to achieve this UI by using view pager indicator? Do you have any idea/tutorial?

I have created this UI using the normal view pager indicator, but i dont really understand how to do this. I dont understand **where to start**.

Feel free to ask any question, and thanks a lot for your time.

**UPDATE 1**

Right now, i try to use `iconPageIndicator` and modify the `notifyDataSetChanged` to create a bigger icon :

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    mIconsLayout.removeAllViews();
    IconPagerAdapter iconAdapter = (IconPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
    int count = iconAdapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(getContext(), null, R.attr.vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle);
        view.setImageResource(iconAdapter.getIconResId(i));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        mIconsLayout.addView(view);
    }
    if (mSelectedIndex > count) {
        mSelectedIndex = count - 1;
    }
    setCurrentItem(mSelectedIndex);
    requestLayout();
}
```

Now the moving fragment and bigger indicator icon is accomplished, the last (i hope) problem is how to dynamically hide/show the icon based on the selected icon. (Please kindly see my scenario above)

So, my current condition is all of the 5 icon is showed, instead of 3 with changing those icon's image based on their position.(again, its in my scenario)

Comment: You can override ViewPager's OnPagerChangeListner and you can set whatever you want to set your current item.

Comment: see : https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Ok i will try that, still need some guide here :D

Comment: Have anyone accomplished this?